# Product of $\cos\theta$ or $\sin\theta$ and a Spherical Harmonic

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, spherical-harmonics

To mix an orientation vector in spherical coordinates with a Spherical Harmonic, I am trying to find an expression for the product of $\cos\phi\sin\theta$, $\sin\phi\sin\theta$ or $\cos\theta$ with a spherical harmonic function $Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)$. What I found so far, it that is seems like this product can be expanded into no more than 2 spherical harmonics in the case of $\cos\theta Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)$ or no more than 4 spherical harmonics in the case of $\sin\phi\sin\theta Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)$ and $\cos\phi\sin\theta Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)$. It seems like:

$$\cos\theta Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)=c_+(l,m) Y_{l+1}^m(\theta,\phi)+c_-(l,m) Y_{l-1}^m(\theta,\phi)$$

(so long as $Y_{l-1}^m(\theta,\phi)$ exists, that is $l-1\geq|m|$)

and

$$\sin\phi\sin\theta Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)=c_{++}(l,m) Y_{l+1}^{m+1}(\theta,\phi)+c_{+-}(l,m) Y_{l+1}^{m-1}(\theta,\phi)+c_{-+}(l,m) Y_{l-1}^{m+1}+c_{--}(l,m) Y_{l-1}^{m-1},$$
$$\cos\phi\sin\theta Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)=c'_{++}(l,m) Y_{l+1}^{m+1}(\theta,\phi)+c'_{+-}(l,m) Y_{l+1}^{m-1}(\theta,\phi)+c'_{-+}(l,m) Y_{l-1}^{m+1}+c'_{--}(l,m) Y_{l-1}^{m-1}$$

(again, so long as all spherical harmonics exists)

I can't seem to find the analytical expressions for $c_+(l,m)$, $c_-(l,m)$, $c_{++}(l,m)$, $c_{+-}(l,m)$, $c_{-+}(l,m)$, $c_{--}(l,m)$, $c'_{++}(l,m)$, $c'_{+-}(l,m)$, $c'_{-+}(l,m)$ and $c'_{--}(l,m)$.

Does anyone know how to come up with closed expressions for these prefactors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $\cos\theta$ as a multiple of $Y_1^0$, $\sin\theta \cos\phi$ and $\sin\theta \sin\phi$ as a linear combination of $Y_1^1$ and $Y_1^{-1}$, and then use the standard expansion of products of spherical harmonics with the [Clebsch Gordan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients) coefficients or Wigner coefficients. The selection rules of these coefficients will filter the surviving terms of $Y_{l\pm 1}$

Comment: Thanks! I will try this and report back if it worked out!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the solution strategy suggested in the answer by R.J. Mather seems to have worked out. I will accept his answer, but write the resulting expression from my derivations here as well for future reference:

\begin{align}
    \sin\theta\cos\phi Y_l^m&=\sum_{L=l-1}^{l+1} \sqrt{\frac{2l+1}{2(2L+1)}}C_{10l0}^{L0}\left(-C_{11lm}^{L,m+1}Y_L^{m+1}+C_{1-1lm}^{L,m-1}Y_L^{m-1}\right),\\
    \sin\theta\sin\phi Y_l^m&=\sum_{L=l-1}^{l+1} i\sqrt{\frac{2l+1}{2(2L+1)}}C_{10l0}^{L0}\left(C_{11lm}^{L,m+1}Y_L^{m+1}+C_{1-1lm}^{L,m-1}Y_L^{m-1}\right),\\
    \cos\theta Y_l^m&=\sum_{L=l-1}^{l+1} \sqrt{\frac{2 l+1}{2 L+1}} C_{10l0}^{L0} C_{10lm}^{Lm} Y_L^{m},
\end{align}

Note that the $L=l$ term always vanishes as a consequence of the first CG coefficient (but I could not come up with a shorter notation to eliminate this term from the sum, so just left the expression like this)